# In MTG, what happens when Sakashima the Imposter copies Halcyon Glaze?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I cast [Sakashima the Imposter](http://magiccards.info/sok/en/53.html), copying [Halcyon Glaze](http://magiccards.info/rav/en/54.html), what happens?

My guess is that Sakashima becomes a 4/4 Enchantment Creature - Illusion until the end of the turn (that's the current state of Halcyon Glaze) with Halcyon Glaze's text ("Whenever you play a creature spell...").

So, Sakashima would revert to a 3/1 with Halcyon Glaze's text at the end of the turn. This means that on future turns, if I cast a creature spell, Sakashima would again become a 4/4.

Something about that doesn't seem quite right, however. What actually happens?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A relevant paragraph from the MtG Comprehensive Rules:

> 706.2. When copying an object, the copy acquires the copiable values of
>   the original object's characteristics
>   and, for an object on the stack,
>   choices made when casting or
>   activating it (mode, targets, the
>   value of X, whether it was kicked, how
>   it will affect multiple targets, and
>   so on). The "copiable values" are the
>   values derived from the text printed
>   on the object (that text being name,
>   mana cost, card type, subtype,
>   supertype, expansion symbol, rules
>   text, power, toughness, and/or
>   loyalty), as modified by other copy
>   effects, by "as . . . enters the
>   battlefield" and "as . . . is turned
>   face up" abilities that set
>   characteristics, and by abilities that
>   caused the object to be face down.
>   Other effects (including type-changing
>   and text-changing effects), status,
>   and counters are not copied. **Example:
>   Chimeric Staff is an artifact that
>   reads "{X}: Chimeric Staff becomes an
>   X/X artifact creature until end of
>   turn." Clone is a creature that reads,
>   "You may have Clone enter the
>   battlefield as a copy of any creature
>   on the battlefield." After a Staff has
>   become a 5/5 artifact creature, a
>   Clone enters the battlefield as a copy
>   of it. The Clone is an artifact, not a
>   5/5 artifact creature. (The copy has
>   the Staff's ability, however, and will
>   become a creature if that ability is
>   activated.)** Example: Clone enters the
>   battlefield as a copy of a face-down
>   Grinning Demon (a creature with morph
>   {2}{B}{B}). The Clone is a colorless
>   2/2 creature with no name, no types,
>   no abilities, and no mana cost. It
>   will still be face up. Its controller
>   can't pay {2}{B}{B} to turn it face
>   up.

I think that what this implies is that Sakashima does NOT become a 4/4 creature when copying a creatured-up Halcyon Glaze, but rather an enchantment with Halcyon Glaze's rules text.  So you'd have to cast another creature to turn enchantment-Sakashima into a 4/4 flyer.  I don't think he'd revert to being a 3/1 at end of turn; he'd stay a noncreature enchantment until returned to hand with Sakashima's ability.

Essentially the key issue here is about what the Magic rules like to call "copiable values". The switched-on Glaze is a valid thing for Sakashima to copy, because it's a creature in play, but its switched-on status is not a copiable value. So Sakashima just becomes a switched-off Glaze, with all the extra characteristics as defined in the Sakashima rules text.

Answer (score -2):

nope, it is not a legal target cause it clearly says "except it is still an enchantment"

Comment: It's an enchantment that is also a creature though.  See Lucent Liminid (http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=130691) if you need proof that this is possible :)

Comment: Also, Sakashima's ability doesn't target.